# Need to Send Clickable links in Direct_message Python Instagram API

Tags: python, instagram-api

I am trying to send Links in Message, and the problem is those links are appear as string, and not clickable, i wanted to make them clickable..
I Use LevPasha Instagram-Api with python,

Here is My code summary,

```
message = "bla blaa blaaa https://facebook.com blaa blaa blaaaa"
self.api.direct_message(message,user_id)
```